# import jquery, easyui and more scripts in aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, import

This is strange problem. I want to use easyuis drad-and-drop capabilities, so I need to import jquery and easyui libs in aspx page. This should be fairly easy, but...

I tried many times with code like this

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.easyui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/drag_and_drop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

where drag_and_drop.js is

```
function OnDrag() {
    $('module1').draggable();

};
```

and i call function here

```
<body>
    <div id="module1" runat="server" oninit="OnDrag()">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/mickey.jpg" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</body>
```

This all do not work for some reason.

I tried pasting entire libs of jquery and easyui in script tag inside head tag, and everything worked fine. This made me understand that there is problem with importing libs to aspx.

What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance...

Comment: what is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: It says that do not recognize control OnDrag() when it is called inside div...

Comment: there is not a oninit event in a dom,so that it can not fire the javascript function OnDrag()

Comment: so witch event you suggest?, I also tried onload, same thing...

Comment: where did you mean to put $(document).ready()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `oninit` from the div tag, then add this bit of code in your head of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('module1').draggable();
    });
</script>
```

This will run the `draggable()` method when the DOM is ready, and should work

**EDIT**
Try using the jQuery-UI draggable instead. 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

You can then get rid of your jquery.easyui.min.js and drag_and_drop.js scripts.

Comment: now there is no error, but function does not work, image is not drag-able :)

Comment: thanks dude, i worked out the problem... I had to add put '#module1' instead 'module'

Comment: d'oh, should have noticed that!